# React antd expandedRowRender - Only open one row at a time

Tags: reactjs, antd

I created a react table and use [ant design](https://ant.design).

Is there a solution with ant design to allow the `expandedRowRender` function only for one row at a time.

I want to hide all other expand icons if one row is expanded.

Comment: Did you got any solution regarding your query??

Comment: pass rowKey parameter to the table component

Answer (score 13):

It is quite simple to do. You will need to take advantage of `expandedRowKeys` property of `<Table />` component. That property stores values of row keys that are currently expanded. So, what we have to do is just set only current expanded row keys on it and delete any others.

### `render()`

```
<Table
    expandedRowKeys={this.state.expandedRowKeys}
    onExpand={this.onTableRowExpand}
/>
```

### `onExpand` Callback

```
onTableRowExpand(expanded, record){
    var keys = [];
    if(expanded){
        keys.push(record.id); // I have set my record.id as row key. Check the documentation for more details.
    }

    this.setState({expandedRowKeys: keys});
}
```

**More Read:** [`<Table />` API Documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/#API)

## Update 2021

If you are using hooks

```
// useState()
const [expandedRowKeys, setExpandedRowKeys] = useState([]);
```

### `render()`

```
<Table
    expandedRowKeys={expandedRowKeys}
    onExpand={onTableRowExpand}
/>
```

### `onExpand` Callback

```
const onTableRowExpand = (expanded, record) => {
    const keys = [];
    if(expanded){
        keys.push(record.id); // I have set my record.id as row key. Check the documentation for more details.
    }

    setExpandedRowKeys(keys);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434856/expand-only-one-table-row-at-a-time-ant-design-react please have a look.

Comment: Another way to write the onExpand callback: `const onTableRowExpand = (expanded, { id }) => { setExpandedRowKeys(expanded ? [id] : []);};`