# React + Antd: hide previous expanded row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Using React + Antd table

I want only one row to be expanded, so can i hide previous expanded row in onExpand function?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a code snippet to understand it better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React antd expandedRowRender - Only open one row at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46241394/react-antd-expandedrowrender-only-open-one-row-at-a-time)

Comment: thank you, it works!)